# What package now provides \NewDocumentCommand?

Tags: packages, xparse

I see that I can use the command `\NewDocumentCommand`
without adding `\usepackage{xparse}`

What package contains `\NewDocumentCommand`?

Is there a package that contains the `xparse` package?

Does any LaTeX compiler always contain it or is it only when using XeLaTeX?

Comment: Since 2020-10-01, (most of) `xparse` is built into LaTeX itself.

Comment: Most of xparse is now directly in the latex kernel, no package needed

Comment: And do remember NewDocumentCommand, case matters

Comment: If you can put a more detailed answer of which parts I'd gladly mark your answer as the answer.

Comment: @Toma Added, with a few relevant links

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since the 2020-10-01 release, most of<sup>[1]</sup> `xparse` (rebranded as `ltcmd`) is built into the LaTeX kernel, so `\NewDocumentCommand` is available out of the box (see section **Providing `xparse` in the format** in the [ltnews32](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/ltnews32.pdf)).

---

<sup>1: Some argument types, considered bad practice, were considered deprecated and not moved to the kernel (see [this blog post on that](https://www.texdev.net/2020/08/19/the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-creating-document-commands)).  To use these argument types you still have to load the `xparse` package.</sup>